# ngAnimate on route change using different animation according to class element

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, angular-routing, ng-animate

I want to simulate the horizontal parallax effect on page transition, using the classes `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` added by ngAnimate.
The idea is to use different  speed for the elements in the page, to have a "3d deep effect" when the elements slide to the left. This is my not-working code

```
   <style>
    @keyframes slideOutLeft {
        to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
    }

    #container.ng-enter .layer-one        
         {animation: slideOutLeft 1s both ease-in-out; }

    #container.ng-enter .layer-two       
         { animation: slideOutLeft 2s both ease-in-out; }

    #container.ng-enter .layer-three        
         { animation: slideOutLeft 3s both ease-in-out; }

    </style>

  <div ng-view id="container">  
    <ul id="photography-scene">
        <li class="layer-one"
            <img  src="back.jpg"  />
        </li>
        <li class="layer-two"
            <img  src="mid.jpg"  />
        </li>
        <li class="layer-three"
            <img  src="front.jpg"  />
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

this is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0sv6uhbq/6/) of my code. In CSS, I defined different animations for elements .one and .two . If I remove these two classes, and leave  the animation for the whole ngView, everything works

Comment: mmh sorry..I don't think I got it... what do you mean? I defined the style in the <style> tag

Comment: ng-enter and ng-leave are classes added automatically by ngAnimate

Comment: can you add the code how you specified the controller, and you html code

Comment: done, I added a jsfiddle

Comment: what do you want to achieve using class one and two

Comment: different animation speed for each element. So .one will slide in 1second, .two in 3 seconds, obtaining a parallax effect

Comment: do you want hello1 to come first on the screen and hello2 later?

Comment: check if this will work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0sv6uhbq/7/

Comment: it works!  thank you so much!!!   anyway....  .one and .two are children of ngview, aren't they?  Why I should use the comma?

Comment: sorry i won't be able to answer that because i'm not good at theory, I can just get the desired result :P

Comment: I am sorry, actually it doesn't work....  it animates without considering ng-enter or ng-leave, it always animates :(